# primefaces 4 datatable pager works only after first ajax update

Tags: primefaces, datatable, pagination

i have an primefaces 4 datatable, when loading the page the paginator isn't working.. when i click the button nothing happens. But the first data is shown. Wehn i now sort/filter the table once the paginator starts to work.

```
        <p:dataTable var="user" value="#{proxyUserListHandler.lazyModel}" paginator="true" rows="10" paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,50,100,200,500" lazy="true">

            <p:column headerText="Id" sortBy="id" filterBy="#{user.id}">
                <h:outputText value="#{user.id}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Username" sortBy="username" filterBy="#{user.username}">
                <h:outputText value="#{user.username}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="apiKey" sortBy="apiKey" filterBy="#{user.apiKey}">
                <h:outputText value="#{user.apiKey}" />
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was

```
<p:dataTable value="#{listHandler.lazyModel}"
```

the function always returned a new LazyModel...somehow the function is called twice and only at the first object the "load" function was called.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have another error on the page that you are not noticing (and quite likely is not being reported!)

Try to reduce the page functionality to the bare min in order to get the data table to react properly, then add the other page components back in until the datatable bahavior is impacted again.

Comment: my page only contains this table... and weather javascript console nor tomcat spits any errors =( same behaviour in FF and chrome

Comment: I suspect the lazy loading.  Try turning that to false to test it.  The sorting, which causes it to work after, requires that all data is loading, by-passing lazy.

Comment: i tried lazy="false" but now nothing is loaded and the table shows "No records found."